# Is it possible to check .Bak File is corrupted or not without Restoring it

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a backup file of SQL Database. For Example MyDB.bak. I want to check MyDB.bak file is corrupted or not. Is there any way to check my database backup condition either corrupted or in good condition?

**Note**: I dont want to restore that .bak file.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly as stakx said. See the link for how to use the command:
[how to use RESTORE VERIFYONLY](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/113/checking-to-make-sure-a-sql-server-backup-is-useable/)

**Check a backup file on disk**

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = C:\AdventureWorks.BAK
GO
```

**Check a backup file on disk for a particular backup**

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = C:\AdventureWorks.BAK WITH FILE = 2
GO
```

This command will check the second backup in this backup file. To check the contents in a backup you can use RESTORE HEADERONLY and use the Position column to specify the FILE number.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers.  I have corrupted database backup file. But when I run RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = C:\MyDB.BAK
query it shows me message "The backup set on file 1 is valid."....

Comment: Well, after looking into it a little deeper, I came to the conclusion that the only way to be 100% sure for your .bak validation is to restore it :( . You can use VERIFYONLY which will give you some sort of result but doubtful. Maybe it can produce less doubtful results if you include a Checksum in your original backup (before generating it), but again you can't rely on that in case of a positive result.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that's what [`RESTORE VERIFYONLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx) is for.

> *"Verifies the backup but does not restore it, and checks to see that the backup set is complete and the entire backup is readable. However, RESTORE VERIFYONLY does not attempt to verify the structure of the data contained in the backup volumes. […] If the backup is valid, the SQL Server Database Engine returns a success message. "*